# Can you embed a FlexCard inside a custom LWC?

Tags: omnistudio

I would like to replace a record action button that uses an LWC to perform a get request to populate product data in a separate screen.
I would like to use this same record action button that opens a new LWC page with the flexcard (that performs the integration procedure call to retrieve data and populate the screen). I'm trying to use the navigatemixin function to call the cfContractLifeFlexCardV1BillingAndPayments flexcard I created once the user clicks on the record action LWC button it will open a new page with the flexcard's screen w/data. I see documentation on how to embed a custom LWC inside a Flexcard but not the otherway around. I don't see much documentation out there for embedding a Flexcard inside a custom LWC. Any help is appreciated!

Sample code of attempt implementation:

```javascript
export default class ReplaceLWCRecordActionButton extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    _recordId;
    @api set recordId(recordId) {
        if (recordId !== this._recordId) {
            this._recordId = recordId;
        }
    }
    get recordId() {
        return this._recordId;
    }

    @api async invoke() {
        try {

            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__component',
                attributes: {
                    componentName: 'omnistudio__vlocityLWCOmniWrapper'
                },
                state: {
                    cf__target: 'cfContractLifeFlexCardV1BillingAndPayments',
                    cf__layout: 'lightning',
                    /*c__target: 'cfContractLifeFlexCardV1BillingAndPayments',
                    c__layout: 'lightning',*/
                    recordId: this.recordId
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({title: 'Navigation Error', message: error?.body?.message, variant: 'error'})
            );
        }
    }
```